# Ruby on Rails Textbook Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to follow the textbook for Ruby on Rails (Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Ed. by Michael Hartl), but I'm having trouble with section 1.5. I'm operating in Cloud9 IDE, and I've followed all other steps in the text. When I try to run heroku create, I get this error:

```
 !   Error in heroku-apps:
 !   Cannot find module 'filesize'
 !   See /home/ubuntu/.heroku/error.log for more info.
```

I've searched for other people who ran into the same error but there doesn't seem to be a lot of help out there. A lot of people have been told to run the command heroku run bash, but when I try to do that I get an error saying that heroku doesn't know which app to run bash on (which I understand, because I haven't created an app with heroku yet!). Here are the results found in /home/ubuntu/.heroku/error.log:

```
2016/03/28 14:59:13 Error during create:null
2016/03/28 14:59:13 Error: Cannot find module 'filesize'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-apps/commands/apps/info.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I started the Tutorial again, following the instructions on the book's website:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book

The second time, I received no error. You may try.

Comment: This worked for me. Still frustrating it has to happen this way, though.